# What are the "Conventional Techniques" to avoid deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I saw the below statement in Java Specifications.

> Programs where threads hold (directly
>   or indirectly) locks on multiple
>   objects should use conventional
>   techniques for deadlock avoidance,
>   creating higher-level locking
>   primitives that don't deadlock, if
>   necessary.

So, What are the "Conventional Techniques" to follow to avoid deadlock? I'm not pretty clear with this (not understood properly, explanation needed).

Comment: follow the hierarchy and dont cross-lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common technique is to acquire resources (locks) in some consistent well-defined order.

The following article by Brian Goetz might be helpful: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1012-deadlock.html

It's pretty old, but explains the issues well.

Comment: Yes, although not nesting locks is probably going to be easier.

Comment: Or, by extension, not programming at all :) - sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 1):

As a somewhat absract suggestion, an answer to this might be "Have a plan for handling locks and stick to it".

The danger of locking is where, in short, one thread holds lock A and is trying to get lock B, while another thread holds lock B and is trying to get lock A. As noted by another answer, the clasic way to avoid this is to get locks in a consistent order. However, a good discipline is to minimize the amount of work that your code does with a lock held. Any code that calls another function with a lock held is a potential problem: what if that other function tries to get another lock? What if someone else later modifies that function to get a lock? Try to form a clear pattern of what functions can be called with locks held, and what cannot, and make sure the comments in your code make this all clear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do locking! Seriously. We get immense performance (100k's of transactions at sub-millisecond latency) at my work by keeping all our business logic single threaded.