# Synchronization paragraph from java documentation

Tags: java

everyone!

I am reading java doc from this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html

Could anyone,please, tell more about

> The Java programming language neither prevents nor requires detection
>   of deadlock conditions. Programs where threads hold (directly or
>   indirectly) locks on multiple objects should use conventional
>   techniques for deadlock avoidance, creating higher-level locking
>   primitives that do not deadlock, if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: In the future (and even now with an edit), please make your questions clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that "Do not expect java to handle OR avoid deadlocks for you. If you do not write your code properly then there is no way java will tell you in advance. So, it is your responsibility to make sure your code does not cause any deadlocks".

Comment: Thanks. What does "conventional techniques" and " higher-level locking primitives" mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155013/what-are-the-conventional-techniques-to-avoid-deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this paragraph states that Java won't handle deadlocks for you - it's your responsibility to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks. I don't clearly understand sentences on above my comment.